# How do you make Rails route everything under a path to a Rack app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I'm trying to capture all requests to `/dav` and all paths nested under that to a Rack handler:

```
match "/dav" =>  RackDAV::Handler.new(:root => 'davdocs')
match "/dav/*whatever" =>  RackDAV::Handler.new(:root => 'davdocs')
```

Do I really have to make two routes for this, or is there a way to express this as one route (one line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be enough to use

```
match "/dav(/*whatever)" =>  RackDAV::Handler.new(:root => 'davdocs')
```

Optional parameters are very briefly described in the Rails Routing guide under "[Bound parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters)"

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/dav(/*dav_section)', :to =>  Proc.new { |env| [200, {"Content-Type" => 'text/plain'},["Here we are in Dav"]]}
```